# У меня задание сделать код js для высчитывания примера, ниже мой код

Tags: javascript, математика

в нем ошибка ибо мне не выдаёт значение в (document.write),на код с временем можно не смотреть, он рабочий, буду признателен помощи)

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>1</TITLE>
<noscript>
    Ваш браузер не поддерживает javascript
</noscript>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var now = new Date();
var y = now.getHours();
if  ((y>= 7)&&(y< 12)) alert('Доброе утро');
if  ((y>= 12)&&(y< 17)) alert('Добрый день');
if  ((y>= 17)&&(y< 23)) alert('Добрый вечер');
if  ((y>= 0)&&(y< 7)) alert('Доброй ночи');
</script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function math()
 {
    var xn = document.forms[0].elements[0].value;
    var xk = document.forms[0].elements[1].value;
    var s = document.forms[0].elements[2].value;
    var i =0;
    var y=0;
    for (i = 0; i <= 1; )
     {
        if(xn<=xk)
        {
            y = ((2**xn)/((2*xn-3)(2*xn-2))**3);
            xn=xn+s;

        }
        else { i++; }
     }
    document.write(y+'; ');
}
</script>
Решение примера:
<img src="1.jpg.png"><p>
    <p>
<form name="my">
Введите начальный x<input type="text"><p>
Введите конечный x <input  type="text"><p>
шаг                <input  type="text"><p>
<input type="button" value="Решить"onclick="math();">
</form>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: А как сформулирована задача? `y = ((2**xn)/((2*xn-3)(2*xn-2))**3);` такое нет смысла делать в цикле, может там `y += ` ? `(2*xn-3) * (2*xn-2)` — между скобок нужен знак умножения. Цикл с else i++... Это равносильно `while (xn<=xk) {  }` без for или if. *А в формуле, в данном виде, всё целиком после деления, возводится в куб, а не только знаменатель.

Answer (score 1):

Как то так я думаю

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>1</TITLE>
<noscript>
    Ваш браузер не поддерживает javascript
</noscript>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var now = new Date();
var y = now.getHours();
if  ((y>= 7)&&(y< 12)) alert('Доброе утро');
if  ((y>= 12)&&(y< 17)) alert('Добрый день');
if  ((y>= 17)&&(y< 23)) alert('Добрый вечер');
if  ((y>= 0)&&(y< 7)) alert('Доброй ночи');
</script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function math()
 {
    var xn = +document.forms[0].elements[0].value;
    var xk = +document.forms[0].elements[1].value;
    var s = +document.forms[0].elements[2].value;
    var i =0;
    var y=0;
    for (i = 0; i <= 1; )
     {
        if(xn<=xk)
        {
            y = ((2**xn)/((2*xn-3)*(2*xn-2))**3);
            xn=xn+s;

        }
        else { i++; }
     }
    document.write(y+'; ');
}
</script>
Решение примера:
<img src="1.jpg.png"><p>
    <p>
<form name="my">
Введите начальный x<input type="text"><p>
Введите конечный x <input  type="text"><p>
шаг                <input  type="text"><p>
<input type="button" value="Решить"onclick="math();">
</form>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

У вас нет преобразования string в number и нет произведения между скобками